# How to make the page number appear on the abbreviation list?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, nomenclature

does anybody know how to make the first page of the abbreviation list have the page number? My abbrev. list is made of 3 pages and only the other two have the correct page numbering (roman). The first page is plain.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\linespread{1.6}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{includeheadfoot,
  headheight=14pt,
  left=4cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=2.5cm,
  bottom=2.5cm}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\urlstyle{same}
\title{} \author{} \date{}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\listoffigures 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\thispagestyle{fancy} 

\listoftables 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\thispagestyle{fancy} 

\printnomenclature 
\thispagestyle{fancy} 

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter*{Introduction}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} 
\thispagestyle{fancy} 

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{apsr}

\bibliography{bibliothesis}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) your example isn't really minimal.  it contains several components (e.g. bibliography) that aren't needed, but more importantly, it doesn't generate any nomenclature file to illustrate the problem you inquired about.

Comment: hello thanks. sorry i'm new to latex. what do you mean to generate nomenclature file? Do you want me to upload the actual pdf page with the list of abbreviations?

Comment: you need some actual `\nomenclature{...}` entries in the file.  they will cause a separate nomenclature file to be generated that will be read in by the `\printnomenclature` command.  however, a `\thispagestyle{...}` command isn't read in until after processing of the preceding command is complete, so if you have a multi-page list (of any kind -- contents, list of tables, nomenclature, ...) the page style will be applied only to the last page of that section.  i may not be able to help with that, since i don't use `nomencl`, but other potential assistants will need the "improved" file.

Comment: Thanks very much. I added the \nomenclature{} in the not so Minimal WE. That's interesting what you say. The fact is that the page number appears on the first page of both the LOT and LOF (but these two are only single-page lists)

Comment: any help? I'm submitting the thesis tomorrow and I'd love to sort out that issue. They're very strict with layout rules at my uni

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late, but here is a solution: To have the first page of the nomenclature carry your fancy page style, issue

```
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```

in your preamble.

Moreover, to have the roman numbering continue through the nomenclature, issue a `\clearpage` after `\printnomenclature`, otherwise the following `\pagenumbering{arabic}` will be applied to the last page of the nomenclature. To summarize, it should look like this:

```
...
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}
\printnomenclature 
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
...
```

The *real* problem, however, is the way you (try to) change the `plain` page style. This style will automatically applied on all first pages of chapters, so also on the first page of the nomenclature. You missed the braces, it should look like this:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% an opening brace here
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
}% a closing brace here
```

That way, the redefinition of `\nompreamble` is not necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `\thispagestyle{plain}` (as the nomenclature is a chapter)?

Comment: @lockstep No, as this leads exactly to the swallowed page number on the first page of the nomenclature.

Comment: Strange ... normally, `plain` displays the page number.

Comment: @lockstep Of course. And now I see the real culprit...

Comment: Dang ... could it be `\fancypagestyle}{plain}` without a second argument?